# what is the performacne impact on instrumented jars vs non instrumented jars

Tags: java, performance, instrumentation, cobertura

What would be the performance impact if I instrument my java classes with cobertura or clover and deploy vs not instrument jars and deploy ?

Will this have any significant difference in how application performs ? I tried this test on my web application(locally), which is really small and I am not able to notice any difference in performance, but I would like to know how much impact does it have on a big projects like a heavy web server that takes around 50 requests per sec.

Comment: I seriously doubt you will ever notice.

Comment: The main difference is the time it takes to set up the trap set.  (It *is* Friday afternoon, after all.)

Answer (score 0):

This will have a performance impact on a larger web application project's performance.  Cobertura and Clover both do compile time instrumentation which modifies the byte code to all instructions to write the coverage data to disk or where-ever you have specified.  The performance impact will be relative to the amount of code instrumented so if you only instrument your client code and not all the dependencies that will lessen the impact.  You will need to test empirically to get a good idea what the impact will be.

Answer (score 0):

Performance impact for an instrumented code may vary very significantly, depending on the kind of an application you have. Usually, an impact is high for CPU-intensive operations and rather low when your application performs a lot of I/0 operations (as CPU is just waiting in such case).

In case of Clover, it adds an extra instruction (a method call of the coverage recorder) for every:

- method entry
- code statement
- true and false condition in a boolean expression

You can find some sample performance data here:

- https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Clover+Performance+Tuning

Please keep in mind that it's just sample data. The best is to measure performance of your own application.